# ngModel data binding is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using ngSwitch directive to switch the view to Edit the div content. HTML is as follows -

```
     <div ng-switch="isEditing" ng-controller="descController">
      <div ng-switch-when="true">
          <textarea name="Name" rows="8" class="form-control" ng-model="desc"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveEdit($parent)">Save</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancelEdit($parent);">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-default>
          <p class="lead" >{{desc}}</p>
          <p><button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" ng-click="$parent.isEditing = true;">Edit</button></p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

The controller code is as follows

```
home.controller("descController", function($scope, Desc){

(function getAboutMe(){
    Desc.getAboutMe().success(function(about){
        $scope.desc = about[0].description;
        $scope.actualText = about[0].description;

        $scope.saveEdit = function($parent){

            //$scope.desc = $scope.desc;
            $parent.isEditing = false;
        }

        $scope.cancelEdit = function($parent){

            $scope.desc = $scope.actualText;
            $parent.isEditing = false;
        };
    }).error(function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
})();


});
```

What I am trying to do is, when the cancel button is pressed I want the original text to be visible on the div and when the save button is clicked I want the new text to be visible on the div. How can i achieve this? I am new to Angular.

Comment: I would appreciate a solution or a guidance (for an inspiration to learn more and dig more) instead of a down vote. Or at least an explanation for down vote will help me either improve my question or provide my research input or my understanding of the topic.

Comment: I did not point you Khanh. I don't know who down voted the question. The comment was in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
$scope.saveEdit = function($parent){
            $scope.actualText = $scope.desc; //update actualText before switching to view mode
            $parent.isEditing = false;
        }

        $scope.cancelEdit = function($parent){
            $scope.desc = $scope.actualText; //restore des
            $parent.isEditing = false;
        };
```

The main problem is `ng-switch` creates a new scope. Therefore you need to bind to the parent scope in your textarea using $parent:

```
<textarea name="Name" rows="8" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.desc"></textarea>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WS8hX/1/)

Comment: dude.. you saved me from a severe headache.. thanks for this line *The main problem is ng-switch creates a new scope.*